# Error broken count>0 unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, sudo, dependencies

I have the red error icon on the headings, and I followed many advice from the forum but none of them worked for me. I use Ubuntu in Hungarian but maybe you can read out the important stuff from the error message. I typed in `sudo apt-get install -f` and this is the result:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  kde-config-telepathy-accounts
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  kde-config-telepathy-accounts
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 362 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/137 kB of archives.
After this operation, 825 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 213142 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../kde-config-telepathy- accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking kde-config-telepathy-accounts (4:15.12.3-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/accounts/services/google-im.service', which is also in package account-plugin-google 0.12+16.04.20160126-0ubuntu1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

EDIT!:

```
~$ sudo apt-get autoremove  kde-config-telepathy-accounts
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'kde-config-telepathy-accounts' is not installed, so not removed
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
kde-telepathy-minimal : Depends: kde-config-telepathy-accounts (>= 15.04.0) but it is not going to be installed
 E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
hamana@hamana-AO756:~$ sudo apt-get autoclean
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
hamana@hamana-AO756:~$ sudo apt-get update
Get:1 http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease [247 kB]
Hit:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease               
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [94.5 kB]
Get:4 http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [95.7 kB]
Fetched 437 kB in 1s (338 kB/s)                               
Reading package lists... Done
hamana@hamana-AO756:~$ sudo apt-get --reinstall  kde-config-telepathy-accounts
E: Command line option --reinstall is not understood in combination with the other options
hamana@hamana-AO756:~$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall  kde-config-telepathy-accounts
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  kde-config-telepathy-accounts
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 362 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/137 kB of archives.
After this operation, 825 kB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 213142 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking kde-config-telepathy-accounts (4:15.12.3-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/accounts/services/google-im.service', which is also in package account-plugin-google 0.12+16.04.20160126-0ubuntu1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
hamana@hamana-AO756:~$
```

Comment: Please prepend `LANG=C` to the command, so it communicates in English: `LANG=C sudo apt-get install -f` Then paste the new output into your question.

Comment: Edited! @Melebius

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

if doesn't work then

```
 sudo apt-get autoremove <packagename>
 sudo apt-get autoclean
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install --reinstall <packagename>
```

EDIT :
If it doesn't work then remove sources.list file.and create new sources.list...

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then, type in

```
sudo software-properties-gtk
```

[image]
This will open software-properties-gtk and a newsources.list will be created automatically.

Then change the server to US or to any other server of your choice. You must enable repositories from the new dialog in order to create new sources.list.

Tick all the boxes then click on Revert then click close.

Need to restore default repositories

```
 sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

(it is good practice to backup this file before installing to recover if such things happen)

Comment: None of these worked :S posted in the edit above the result

Comment: U posted output of the install -f command...that will find which package is not completely installed and try to install it again

Comment: Oh ya..now my screen is updated..i can see them

Comment: What were u installing?

Comment: This popped up the second time I booted after installing ubuntu 16.04 LTS. First time i could install darktable (photo workflow software) and Dosbox but after restarting this notification came up and since then I can't install anything. The installing icon goes to the sidebar and stops there.

Comment: See my edit.hope this helps.

Comment: Consider accepting as solution if this helps :)

Comment: It worked finally!! Thank you kind stranger, you are the mostest awesomest!

Comment: Haha...ty...plz tick the √ below downvote and upvote to make it green and accept my answer..so this will be marked as solved