# Aborted package installation, now synaptic and apt won't complete

Tags: apt, package-management, lubuntu, synaptic

Fresh install of lubuntu xenial

Was having issues where print service wasn't found ([this prompt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/575136/printing-service-not-available)).  Cups wasn't installed for some reason (maybe another streamlining choice lubuntu made?).  Tried to install cups `sudo apt-get install cups --install-suggests`  It was doing stuff for hours and slowing down the system.  Trying to look up why it was taking so long (probably suggests was a bad choice?), I closed the terminal window by accident aborting the process.  Now `runit` and `git-daemon-run` are causing issues.  I can't complete anything in synaptic or apt without it being angry that they are broken.

I've tried quite a few things, but here's probably the most relevant thing to paste:

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up runit (2.1.2-3ubuntu1) ...
start: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
dpkg: error processing package runit (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of git-daemon-run:
 git-daemon-run depends on runit; however:
  Package runit is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package git-daemon-run (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 runit
 git-daemon-run
```

Please help!

EDIT: @jokerdino was correct in marking this as a duplicate.  Trying the advice of @minigeek gave the Upstart error mentioned in the dupe link.  Removing runit seems to have worked fine:

```
sudo dpkg -r --force-all runit
sudo apt-get remove --purge git-daemon-run
```

Comment: on boot, the machine shows a bunch of inode error text that I don't recall being there, but that could be coincidental.  there are also random failures that the system wants me to report.  on the plus side, cups and hplip seem to be working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

run :

```
  sudo apt-get install --reinstall runit git-daemon-run
```

If this doesn't solve your problem:

Here i have already written some instructions to repair broken packages or to solve dependency problem refer this :https://askubuntu.com/a/827763/593116